# Heroku: Prevent worker process from restarting?

Tags: heroku, web-worker

I have a Heroku worker setup to do a long running job which iterates over long periods. However whenever I do an update & deploy of other files in the repo this worker restarts, which is annoying, any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

No. This behaviour is part of Heroku's [Automatic Dyno Restarting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

You can't work around this. Instead, you need to build all parts of your app to be able to function properly despite the fact that all dynos will restart at least once every 24 hours or so, whether or not you deploy updates in your repo.

Most significantly, you need to build support for [Graceful Shutdown](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown) into all your processes (e.g. web process and worker processes).